# Move object to existing group without actually moving it in the drawing

Tags: vector, inkscape

After creating an object in the root, I try to move it into an existing group just for better organization and I don't expect anything to happen in the drawing.

I'm a beginner and I fail to understand why you'd want your objects to move around when you just want to reorganize them.

Is it possible to avoid moving the objects when reorganizing your groups?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to add an object to a group without moving it.

Starting with an initial state:

[image: Initial state]

### Method 1: Object Manager

The fastest way, in Inkscape >= 0.91.2, is to use the [Object Manager](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Object_Manager), in **Object** menu:

[image: Object Manager]

You can see the structure of the drawing, show or hide the objects and - in your case - drag them into an existing group:

[image: Drag...]

Once dropped, the object is added to the group:

[image: ...drop!]

### Method 2: XML editor

You can otherwise use the [XML Editor](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/XML.html), which can be useful:

[image: XML Editor]

### Method 3: manual selection

You can also select your group, [ungroup](https://inkscape.org/it/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) it using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, adding the new object to the selection while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, grouping with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: I am already using the object manager. Will try the other methods later. I got the feeling that it only happens to cloned groups.

Comment: The object editor doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @kjohnsen Just tried on Inkscape v.1.1.2 and works as expected. What exactly happens?

Comment: @Paolo I click and drag to move an object into a different group and the object's location changes as soon as it changes groups

Comment: What behavior would you expect?